# Execute push notification after sending message

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, sails.js, chat

I am using sails.socket for message sending. My requirement is that, I have to send a push notification after the success of sent message. How it is possible. Please see the code that I have written.

```
sendChatMessage(chatMessage, function() {
    // calling push notification when a chat message send
    var serverKey       =   req.options.settingsKeyValue.PUSH_SERVER_KEY;
    var typeData        =   { type:1, data:{type:1} };
    var pushData        =   { title:'New Message', body: data };
    pusherService.pushFcm(serverKey,typeData,pushData,toId, function(err, result) {
        if(err) {
            return res.json(200, {status:1, status_type: 'Success', message: 'Error in  sending the message'});
        }else{
            return res.json(200, {status:1, status_type: 'Success', message: 'You have successfully send the message'});
        }
    });
});

function sendChatMessage(){    
    var socketRoom      =   "userRoom_"+toId;
    var roomsSubcribers =   sails.sockets.subscribers(socketRoom);
    console.log("roomsSubcribers");
    console.log(roomsSubcribers);
    var data            =   {
        text: message,
        from_id: fromId,
        from_name: userResult[0].firstName+' '+userResult[0].lastName, from_img : userResult[0].profilePhoto,
    };
    sails.sockets.broadcast(socketRoom,{
        type : "chat",
        message : data,

    });
    callback(chatMessage);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These blocks of code look ok to me... you just have to position them in the right place within your application. Have you tried this?

You definitely need to name some of your arguments in both the `sendChatMessage` function definition, and in your callback function.

Maybe you need something like this:

```
// in some controller

// notice the named arguments 'options' and 'callback'
var sendChatMessage = function(options, callback){    
    var socketRoom      =   "userRoom_"+options.toId;
    var roomsSubcribers =   sails.sockets.subscribers(socketRoom);
    console.log("roomsSubcribers");
    console.log(roomsSubcribers);
    var data            =   {
        text: options.message,
        from_id: options.fromId,
        from_name: options.fromName, 
        from_img : options.fromImg,
    };
    sails.sockets.broadcast(socketRoom,{
        type : "chat",
        message : data,
    });
    callback(data);
};

module.exports = {

    someMethod: function(req, res) {
        // do some work, including defining / getting all options
        var options = {
            toId: 123,
            fromId: 456,
            message: 'test message',
            fromName: 'test user',
            fromImg: 'some/image.jpg' // don't know if you need a source here or what
        };

        // invoke your function - notice the named argument in the callback
        sendChatMessage(options, function(data) {
            // calling push notification when a chat message send
            var serverKey       =   req.options.settingsKeyValue.PUSH_SERVER_KEY;
            var typeData        =   { type:1, data:{type:1} };
            var pushData        =   { title:'New Message', body: data };
            pusherService.pushFcm(serverKey,typeData,pushData,toId, function(err, result) {
                if(err) {
                    return res.json(200, {status:1, status_type: 'Success', message: 'Error in  sending the message'});
                }else{
                    return res.json(200, {status:1, status_type: 'Success', message: 'You have successfully send the message'});
                }
            });
        });
    },

};
```

I can't know if this is the right way to use all your plugins, etc, but putting the pieces together seems to make sense.

Last note, when you define your own callbacks, it's good practice to make the first argument an error object, and check for received errors in the callback body. When successful you can return a null error, like `callback(null, data);`.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks. Let me try